# Parent's scrolling cannot working from iframe - Flutter Web App

Tags: wordpress, flutter, web, iframe, scroll

I created a web app with Flutter for web, and embed to a Wordpress website with iframe. But when I want to scroll iframe to show full web app, it's not working. I just want a performance like the attached gif.

I tried with some css like 'overflow: scroll', 'overflow-scroll:true',...
Many thanks!
[image]

Comment: Hi @Tuan, did you get any solution for this?